# ClassCastException (String to Long) when running a subquery with Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, classcastexception, hibernate-criteria

First my setups :

1. mysql-connector-java 5.1.24
2. hibernate-core 4.1.10.Final

I've got an ClassCastException when running this criteria query :

```
Criteria sellableItemsCriteria = session.createCriteria(MarketData.class, "md");
sellableItemsCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("region", regions));
sellableItemsCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("itemTypeId", items));
DetachedCriteria sellOrderSizeCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(MarketOrder.class);
sellOrderSizeCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("marketDataId", "md.id"));
sellOrderSizeCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("bid", false));
sellOrderSizeCriteria.setProjection(Projections.count("marketDataId"));
sellableItemsCriteria.add(Subqueries.lt(0L, sellOrderSizeCriteria));
```

The exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

The problem is from this line (first i tried with 0 instead of 0L and i got Integer cannot be cast to Long so that why i switched to a Long) :

```
sellableItemsCriteria.add(Subqueries.lt(0L, sellOrderSizeCriteria));
```

And this is the mysql query i want to run :

```
SELECT md.* FROM `marketdata` md
WHERE md.region IN (:regions) 
AND md.item_typeID IN (:items) 
AND (SELECT COUNT(marketData_id) FROM `marketorder` WHERE marketData_id = md.id AND bid = 0) > 0
```

How can i resolve the cast problem ?

Or maybe there is a better way to do this with Criteria ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'll find that the exception comes in fact from this line:

```
sellOrderSizeCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("marketDataId", "md.id"));
```

This line tries to compare the `marketDataId` property of `MarketOrder` to the String `"md.id"`. That's not what you want to do. What you want to do is to compare the `marketDataId` property of `MarketOrder` to the `id` property of `md`. And you thus need to use [eqProperty()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eqProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
sellOrderSizeCriteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("marketDataId", "md.id"));
```

Comment: If the string is `"1"` and long is `1L`, `equals()` returns `false`. Will `eqProperty()` return `true`?

Comment: @acdcjunior: eqProperty compares two properties of two entities in a Criteria query. In the end, the comparison will be done with the generated SQL `=` clause. I don't see what that has to do with the Java equals() method.

Comment: Thanks you were right, got tricked because this restrictions was before the subquery :/.

Comment: @JBNizet I got that from the doc: *Apply an "equal" constraint to two properties*. Anyway, a '1' (varchar) and a 1 (number) will be considered equal by eqProperty?

Comment: No, I don't think you can compare a varchar and a number with = without an explicit cast. That doesn't work on PostgreSQL, at least.